# What is the best/fastest method of filling an array with numbers between two values?

Tags: vb.net

I've got a background thread which adds numbers to an array, this call happens often so i'm just curious if there's a faster method of adding the numbers to the array?

I need to add all the numbers between two values (values will be different depending on the situation), example 1 to 4 which would add 1,2,3 & 4.

However, when I make the call, it would be adding much larger arrays similar to 500 to 1000 etc which sometimes takes a little longer depending on how many numbers need to be added.

At the moment i'm using something similiar to this:

```
    Dim ListOfNumbers As New List(Of Integer)
    For i = 1 To 100000
        If ListOfNumbers.Contains(i) = False Then
            ListOfNumbers.Add(i)
        End If
    Next
```

Is there any other method that I could use which might be faster?

(Avoiding duplicate values in the array if possible)

Comment: Why are you checking if it exists? its a New List so it starts empty, and its in a For loop so `i` is never ever going to be the same as a prev value.  `NumList = Enumerable.Range(min max).ToList()` will do what that code does, leave off the `ToList` and it will get the number when (and if) it is needed rather than doing all of them at once

Comment: You control both the List and the loop. Checking `.Contains()` is not necessary, and probably taking up most of the execution time here. Just remove that check.

Comment: @Plutonix In this example it is a new list, however the list is only created once and is then re-used in the application, I didn't realize `.Contains()` had that much of an impact on time though, even though the list is re-used, the numbers shouldn't be in there anyways due to what it's being used for, I just had it there for convenience, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this is driving your program's performance. Moreover, the best option may depend on how you plan to use these numbers, where you may find you actually can noticeably improve performance by using something like IEnumerable throughout your code, rather than an array.

With that in mind, I suggest this option:

```
int start = 1; int stop = 100000;
var list = Enumerable.Range(start, stop - start).ToArray()
```

Such that you can easily remove the `ToArray()` later if desired.

As for the existing code... You control both the List and the loop. Checking `.Contains()`is not necessary, and probably taking up a significant part of the execution time here. Just remove that check. You can also optimize some by pre-setting the size of the list:

```
Dim size As Integer = 100000
Dim ListOfNumbers As New List(Of Integer)(size)
For i = 1 To size
    ListOfNumbers.Add(i)
Next
```

Comment: I didn't realize `.Contains()` had that much of an impact on time, 
something like `var list = Enumerable.Range(start, stop - start).ToArray()` was what I had in mind from seeing other `.AddRange` examples, I just wasn't sure how to do it, thanks for the help!

Comment: `Enumerable.Range()` is doesn't perform any different... it just hides the loop from you so you don't have write it yourself.

Comment: As for `.Contains()`... imaging you had to write the method yourself? How would have to do it? Now imagine calling this every time you append another number, and think about how the execution cost might grow as your data size gets larger.

Comment: @User7071 What did you think `Contains()` did? The collection is not sorted so it must check each element until it finds it or reaches the end of the collection. That is 100k * (100k/2) ~ O(n^2). Bad